# Firestore (Angularfire) add user as an "admin"

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I need to have an option for creating accounts for users, and give them the accounts. So the accounts should be created by an admin of some company, the users will login with that account and then they can change the password.

I've found one solution, [with Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) but if I understand it correctly, you need your own backend.

Is there any other way? Or do you have another suggestion how to manage this? Basically, a user is suppose to be linked to a company. And he has a role in that company. Admin of the company chooses the role for each user.

Comment: I guess it depends if writing [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) counts as "your own backend" or not.

Comment: Why you mean by your own backend....?

Comment: By that I mean I would have to have my own node.js or whatever code?

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to use the Admin SDK in a callable cloud function to do this.  It is pretty straight forward.

If you do it from the front end when you create the user the admin user is logged out and the new user is logged in.

There is however a hack to do it from the front end without being logged out, by using a secondary firebase app such as below.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
const secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'Secondary');

async registerUser(email, password: string) {
      try {
        const userCredential = await secondaryApp.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        secondaryApp.auth().signOut(); // signout the user that was just created
        // If you wanted to create a document for the user in firestore then you could do it here.
        return userCredential;
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }
    }
```